# Should we keep our SHA-256 public?

Tags: android, sha256, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity, digital-assets-links

When generating a Digital Asset Link we are supposed to asset links file contaning SHA-256 of our android app and post it to https://www.your-host.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started). So is it safe to post our SHA-256 publicly?

Just read through the documentation

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to post the SHA-256 publicly. In fact, the SHA-256 fingerprint can be extracted from any signed API with the following with `keytool -printcert -jarfile [path to APK or AAB] | grep SHA256`. Once installed, any other Android app can also read your SHA-256 key. [Peter's AsseLinks Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool) takes advantage of that to help people find what their SHA-256 key is.